# How can I use an icon for a conditional in Java?

Tags: java, swing, button, icons

I'm working on a TicTacToe game with buttons that shows icons for each move. The issue is that there is no way I found to avoid a button being reused after a turn and the only way I found to avoid the reuse of the button is by setting and text and verifying if the button has that text or not (and then proceed to block the button or not). I would like to know if there is a way to use my icons for the conditional like for example: if the button has an x icon, then the button is blocked. Something like that.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    
    /**
     *
     * @author ItzSebas
     */
    public class TTTApp extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
        TicTacToe game = new TicTacToe();
        JButton board[][] = new JButton[3][3];
        int xScore;
        int oScore;
        int tieScore;
    
        public TTTApp() {
            initComponents();
            setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setResizable(false);
            setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/iconoPrograma.png")).getImage());
            UISetup();
        }
    
        public void UISetup(){
            board[0][0] = button1;
            board[0][1] = button2;
            board[0][2] = button3;
            board[1][0] = button4;
            board[1][1] = button5;
            board[1][2] = button6;
            board[2][0] = button7;
            board[2][1] = button8;
            board[2][2] = button9;
    
            ActionListener clickListener = new ActionListener() {
    
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JButton selected = (JButton) e.getSource();
                    int ROW = 0;
                    int COLUMN = 0;
                    String valueButtonWithoutSpace = selected.getText().replace(" ", "");
    
                    if (valueButtonWithoutSpace == ""){
    
                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                                if (selected == board[i][j]) {
                                    ROW = i;
                                    COLUMN = j;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        TicTacToeTile tile = new TicTacToeTile(ROW, COLUMN);
    
                        if(game.getCurrentTurn().name().equals("X")){
                            selected.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/xMove.png")));
                        }
                        else if(game.getCurrentTurn().name().equals("O")){
                            selected.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/oMove.png")));
                        }
                        //selected.setText(game.getCurrentTurn().name().equals("X") ? "X" : "O");
                        game.playTurn(tile.getRow(), tile.getColumn());
    
                        game.calculateResult();
    
                        if (game.isOver()) {
                            updateGameResults();
                            Boolean done = SafeInput.getYNConfirmDialog("Play Again?");
                            if (!done) {
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                            resetGame();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This button is already used. Pick another one!");
                    }
                }
            };
    
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    board[i][j].addActionListener(clickListener);
                }
            }
        }
    
        public void resetGame(){
            game.reset();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    board[i][j].setText("");
                    board[i][j].setIcon(null);
                }
            }
        }
        public void updateGameResults(){
            if(game.getResult() == "X"){
                xScore += 1;
            }
            else if(game.getResult() == "O"){
                oScore += 1;
            }
            else if(game.getResult() == "Tie!"){
                tieScore += 1;
            }
            xWins.setText(""+xScore);
            oWins.setText(""+oScore);
        }
    
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {
    
            jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            button7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            button8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            button9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            button4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            button5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            button6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            button3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            button2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            button1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            restartButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
            quitButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            oWins = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            xWins = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            player1Label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            player2Label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            titleLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    
            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setLocation(new java.awt.Point(0, 0));
            setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(350, 600));
            setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(350, 600));
    
            jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(247, 249, 248));
    
            jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(247, 249, 248));
            jPanel2.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());
    
            button7.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(247, 255, 255));
            button7.setBorderPainted(false);
            button7.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            button7.setFocusPainted(false);
            button7.setFocusable(false);
            jPanel2.add(button7, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 200, 80, 80));
    
            button8.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(247, 255, 255));
            button8.setBorderPainted(false);
            button8.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            button8.setFocusPainted(false);
            button8.setFocusable(false);
            jPanel2.add(button8, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(110, 200, 90, 80));
    
            button9.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(247, 255, 255));
            button9.setBorderPainted(false);
            button9.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            button9.setFocusPainted(false);
            button9.setFocusable(false);
            jPanel2.add(button9, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(210, 200, 90, 80));
    
            button4.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(247, 255, 255));
            button4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 3)); // NOI18N
            button4.setBorderPainted(false);
            button4.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            button4.setFocusPainted(false);
            button4.setFocusable(false);
            jPanel2.add(button4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 110, 80, 80));
    
            button5.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(247, 255, 255));
            button5.setBorderPainted(false);
            button5.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            button5.setFocusPainted(false);
            button5.setFocusable(false);
            jPanel2.add(button5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(110, 110, 90, 80));
    
            button6.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(247, 255, 255));
            button6.setBorderPainted(false);
            button6.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            button6.setFocusPainted(false);
            button6.setFocusable(false);
            jPanel2.add(button6, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(210, 110, 90, 80));
    
            button3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(247, 255, 255));
            button3.setBorderPainted(false);
            button3.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            button3.setFocusPainted(false);
            button3.setFocusable(false);
            jPanel2.add(button3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(210, 20, 90, 80));
    
            button2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(247, 255, 255));
            button2.setBorderPainted(false);
            button2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            button2.setFocusPainted(false);
            button2.setFocusable(false);
            jPanel2.add(button2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(110, 20, 90, 80));
    
            button1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(247, 255, 255));
            button1.setBorderPainted(false);
            button1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            button1.setFocusPainted(false);
            button1.setFocusable(false);
            jPanel2.add(button1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 20, 80, 80));
    
            jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/fondoTablero.png"))); // NOI18N
            jPanel2.add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 308, -1));
    
            restartButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/restartIcon.png"))); // NOI18N
            restartButton.setBorderPainted(false);
            restartButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            restartButton.setFocusPainted(false);
            restartButton.setPressedIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/restartPress.png"))); // NOI18N
            restartButton.setRolloverIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/restartHover.png"))); // NOI18N
            restartButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    restartButtonActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });
    
            quitButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/exitButton.png"))); // NOI18N
            quitButton.setBorderPainted(false);
            quitButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            quitButton.setFocusPainted(false);
            quitButton.setFocusable(false);
            quitButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
            quitButton.setPressedIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/exitPress.png"))); // NOI18N
            quitButton.setRolloverIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/exitHover.png"))); // NOI18N
            quitButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    quitButtonActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });
    
            jPanel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(247, 249, 248));
            jPanel3.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());
    
            oWins.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
            oWins.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
            jPanel3.add(oWins, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(60, 10, 20, 20));
    
            xWins.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
            xWins.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
            jPanel3.add(xWins, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 10, 20, 20));
    
            jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/scoreBoard.png"))); // NOI18N
            jLabel2.setText("-");
            jLabel2.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
            jPanel3.add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 90, 40));
    
            player1Label.setText("Player 1");
    
            player2Label.setText("  Player 2");
    
            titleLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/logo.png"))); // NOI18N
            titleLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    
            javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
            jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
            jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                    jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                    .addGap(70, 70, 70)
                                                    .addComponent(player1Label)
                                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                    .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                    .addGap(2, 2, 2)
                                                    .addComponent(player2Label))
                                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                    .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                                                    .addComponent(titleLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 325, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                            .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                                                            .addComponent(restartButton)
                                                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                            .addComponent(quitButton))
                                                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                            .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                                                            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 310, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                                    .addContainerGap())
            );
            jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
                    jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                                    .addComponent(titleLabel)
                                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                    .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                                                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                            .addComponent(player1Label)
                                                            .addComponent(player2Label)))
                                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                                    .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                    .addGap(48, 48, 48)
                                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 300, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addComponent(restartButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addComponent(quitButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGap(11, 11, 11))
            );
    
            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );
    
            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>                        
    
        private void restartButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            resetGame();
        }
    
        private void quitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    
        public static void main(String args[]) {
    
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new TTTApp().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
    
        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton button1;
        private javax.swing.JButton button2;
        private javax.swing.JButton button3;
        private javax.swing.JButton button4;
        private javax.swing.JButton button5;
        private javax.swing.JButton button6;
        private javax.swing.JButton button7;
        private javax.swing.JButton button8;
        private javax.swing.JButton button9;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
        private javax.swing.JLabel oWins;
        private javax.swing.JLabel player1Label;
        private javax.swing.JLabel player2Label;
        private javax.swing.JButton quitButton;
        private javax.swing.JButton restartButton;
        private javax.swing.JLabel titleLabel;
        private javax.swing.JLabel xWins;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

Comment: In general, is a bad design to have the application state into the GUI components, you should rather have a 3x3 array, set values into this one and update the GUI accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icons can be shared by multiple components. So there is no need to create a new ImageIcon every time you click on a button.

Instead create an xIcon and oIcon in the constructor of your class to use in later processing.

When you click on a button you can then just use:

```
Icon icon = selected.getIcon();

if (icon == null)
    // do something
```